# How to display Geoserver Map inside the HTML page

Tags: geoserver

I do not have a big idea regarding the [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) But I have a requirement with GeoServer. I have GeoJson file. It is the Map of Madagascar. I need to show that map inside the HTML page.
Can u guide me to do it?